# Mule Joda-time error: later version is required but found version

Tags: mule, jodatime

Mule 3.5 shows the message "later version is required" "but found version" when I try to execute the operation "find object" from the connector Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Mule use an old version of joda-time. 
To use a new version of this lib, I put the jar of the new version in the directory:

${ANYPOINT_HOME}\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.0_3.5.0.201407241708\mule\lib\opt

It´s also necessary to change the file MANIFEST.MF in the directory:

${ANYPOINT_HOME}\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.0_3.5.0.201407241708\META-INF